# Get the JSON object Value from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I can't get the object value to the html id input field.

JSON return

```js
// response from the call
{
  "COLUMNS": ["cityname", "stateabbr"],
  "DATA": [
    ["Culver City", "CA"]
  ]
}

 $.each(response, function(index, zc) {
            $("#cityname").append([zc[0]]);
            $("#stateabbr").append([zc[0]]);
          });
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. If the AJAX works, then please create a [mcve] using just the object , relevant HTML and the success function

Comment: `$("#cityname").append(dat[0]); $("#stateabbr").append(dat[1]);`

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible or typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to to fix for each. try this instead

```
            $("#cityname").val(response.DATA[0][0]);
            $("#stateabbr").val(response.DATA[0][1]);
```

Comment: The console output but no value in the fields.  <input type="text" name="cityname" id="cityname" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="City" maxlength="50">Commerce</input>   <input type="text" name="stateabbr" id="stateabbr" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="State" maxlength="50">CA</input>

Comment: @SMares You should post your view too. I fixed the answer, try again

Comment: That worked thanks, I was breaking my head with almost similar code, now it makes sense how it works.